# Calculate a value from randomly generated numbers which is always positive

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to make sure that the value `tDiscriminant` is always positive. As you can see below, it is calculated from three randomly generated numbers.

```
s = random.uniform(1,100)
sRounded = round(s,1)   
v = random.uniform(1,50)
vRounded = round(v,1)   
a = random.uniform(1,20)
aRounded = round(a,1)
tDiscriminant = (vRounded*vRounded)-(2*aRounded*sRounded)
tDiscriminantRooted = math.sqrt(tDiscriminant)
```

How do I make it so that if `tDiscriminant` is negative, the values `s`, `v` and `a` have to be generated again until `tDiscriminant` is positive?

Comment: Sorry, what was the question here?

Comment: I am not sure I can understand what the question is.

Comment: Yes, it will *usually* be negative.  Describe your desired process for ensuring that it's positive, and show the code that's giving you trouble.

Comment: If you didn't understand the question, it's probably because I accidentally submitted the question before I had finished writing it! I've edited it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
import random
tDiscriminant = -1
while tDiscriminant <= 0:
  s = random.uniform(1,400)
  sRounded = round(s,1)   
  v = random.uniform(1,50)
  vRounded = round(v,1)   
  a = random.uniform(1,20)
  aRounded = round(a,1)
  tDiscriminant = (vRounded*vRounded)-(2*aRounded*sRounded)
tDiscriminantRooted = math.sqrt(tDiscriminant)
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I ran it over 60 times, and it never gave me a negative number...

Comment: Never mind - the algorithm itself is sound, but I think there might be a wider issue with my code.

Comment: Are you copying the exact code? Is there something else in-between the code you gave that is causing this?

Comment: Never mind - I got it working! The issue was that I'd left `tDiscriminantRooted` inside the while loop, so it will have been square-rooting the negative values, rather than waiting for the first positive value. Thank you!